# При редиректе с сервлета на html происходит циклическое перенаправление на странице (не загружается)

Tags: java, html, java-ee, servlet, tomcat

example.html расположен в корне папки webapp.
Пробовал форвард перенаправление, выдаёт 404 ошибку.
При редиректе(код ниже) выдаёт сообщение в браузере: "циклическое перенаправление на странице.."

```
package servlets;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/")
public class Html extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(123);
        resp.sendRedirect("/example.html");
    }
}
```

Вопрос:
как сделать перенаправление с сервлета на html , чтобы она загружалась?

если указать путь сервлета не "/" то загружается. Но с корневого никак не хочет.

Comment: jsp грузится и при форварде и при редиректе без проблем, но хотелось бы html

Comment: Шаблон "/" задаёт сервлет по умолчанию, который перехватывает все запросы, для которых нет своего сервлета. И он перекрывает "системный" сервлет для обработки статических файлов.
Попробуйте в `web.xml` задать `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>default</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`

Comment: @Sergey спасибо! сработало)

Comment: но только в firefox в хроме не грузит если указать сервлет, если не указывать то грузит везде, но сервлет обрабатывает только при загрузке в хроме.

Comment: дело в том, что перед перенаправлением на html мне нужно, что сервлет обработался..

Comment: почистил кеш и куки, вроде бы заработало одинаково и там и там, без указания сервлета, только мапинг

Comment: но работает через раз (страницу открывает, а сервлет то обрабатывает, то нет..) если чистить кеш и куки каждый раз, то отрабатывает

Comment: а иногда нет.. очень странно такое ощущение что попадает то на сервлет, то сразу на html минуя сервлет

Comment: Попробуйте включите в http-заголовки, что сервлета, что страницы запрет кеширования.
Это проще сделать скорей всего через фильтр (тем более для страницы).

Comment: работает, но порою пару раз код перед html отрабатывает.. как будто дважды переходят по адресу